# NextJS Image component won't update to new src

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My src to the image stayed the same,but i've been changing the picture. Reloading won't help, it just stays with same old image. It only updates to new image once i delete the .next folder and rebuild it again. How can i prevent this?

I've tried to import it in different ways,thinking it would help,but no
In this way:
`const mainBanner='/images/mainBanner.png'`
And this:
`import mainBanner from '/images/main_banner.png'`

Comment: it's likely related to Next.js's built-in image optimization and caching, by default, Next.js optimizes and caches images during the build process. This means that if you replace an image file in your project's /public or /static folder, Next.js may still serve the cached version until you rebuild the project.
Have you tried dynamic image imports?

Answer (score -2):

Add the following line in next.config.js file.

```js
const nextConfig = {
    images: {
        unoptimized: true,
    },
}
```